# How to fix "pygame.mixer.music.load()" & "Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll"

Tags: python, windows, pygame, windows-10

We are trying to run pygame's music.load() method in our code.
We are running our file via the Windows Command Line [CMD].
We keep getting this error, anything helps :)

Helpful Information:

- windows 10
- python3.9
- **the code below does not represent the full file**

Code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import * # used in other parts of our code


def play ():
    # Initializing the pygame music feature
    pygame.init()
    mixer.init()

    global stopped
    stopped = False

    play = playlist_box.get(ACTIVE)
    mixer.music.load(play)
    mixer.music.play(loops = 0)
```

Error:

> ```sh
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program >Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Wized\venv\GUI.py", line 95, in play
> mixer.music.load(play)
> pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem today but managed to figure it out. I scrolled through a few pages of google results but there were only a handful of results dedicated to this topic, which I thought was weird until I realized that they were all from the past couple of weeks. This led me to believe that this issue wasn't necessarily related to my code but a bug in a recent pygame update. It seems the devs changed something that broke mixer, as I tried reverting to an older version of pygame and it worked amazingly. Anyways, maybe this is TMI, just thought I'd share my process.

*TL;DR*:
It seems something was changed in a recent pygame update that broke the pygame mixer. Reverting to a previous version of the module using the steps below seems to be a functional temporary workaround while they get everything sorted out.

1. `pip uninstall pygame`
2. `pip install pygame==1.9.6` (I'm currently using 1.9.6; I don't know what other versions work)

PB

Comment: Thanks so much, we will try this process and see how it works. Your help is very much appreciated!